# Roots of $x^n=0$

Tags: complex-numbers, roots, roots-of-unity

Inspired by roots of unity, when we can find the remaining roots of the polynomial $x^n - 1$ using complex exponents, I wonder whether there is any similar way to construct the remaining roots of $x^n$ (that is apart from the trivial $x_0 = 0$) using complex exponentiation.

My first thought was that $e^{i \tau} = 0$, but isn't that just saying the same thing? I mean with that logic, wouldn't $1-1$ also be a distinct root?

**TL;DR** Find all roots of $x^n$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $x^n=0$ has the only root $0$, also in the complex numbers. The complex numbers do not contain zero-divisors.

Comment: There are no roots apart from $0$ because $x^n=(x-0)^n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are n roots of this equation but all of them are equal. Same like we have in perfect squares,cubes,etc.
$x^n=(x-0)^n$
$\Rightarrow x=0$